# Loading same modal with different external values - Passing variables with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a calendar and inside the calendar I have events that you can add. Right now these events are links (`viewevent.php?id=$id`) and that loads a page with the data in it. I've tried with a few modal plugins but can't get any of them to work. The one I really like is SimpleModal OSX style.
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

What would I have to do to integrate this in? I have already tried it, but it only loads one variable for all links.

My calendar file (updated):
http://pastebin.com/BAKPYTgK

My index file (updated):
http://pastebin.com/s9vLC9ff

My viewevent.php file:
http://pastebin.com/dPu0BhSS

I've been stumped on this problem for about 3 hours so any help would be phenomenal. Thank you!

my website with a live preview of this error is http://my.iheff.net/webbook/test.php

Answer (score 1):

You may do all this in one query and one loop.

Rewrite code as

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT b.name as category, title, event_start, event_end FROM events a LEFT JOIN categories b ON a.catid = b.id WHERE a.id=$id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        extract($row);
echo '
       <table class="datatable" align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
           <td><strong>Title:</strong></td>
           <td width="200px">'.$title.'</td>
           <td><strong>Start Date</strong></td>
           <td>'.$event_start.'</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Category:</strong></td>
           <td>'.$category.'</td>
           <td><strong>End Date</strong></td>
           <td>'.$event_end.'</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Organizer:</strong></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><strong>Notes:</strong></td>
           <td width="200px"></td>
       </tr>
       </table>';
    }
```

Also, please note what after

```
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['id']);
```

you don't really need

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

because all non-digits are already removed and no SQL injection will survive this

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I think I'm looking for something different, though. Didn't my code already output an array? On the calendar I'm able to output different events with different categories, but once I try loading it in a modal it only shows the latest id. Here is my website to show you http://my.iheff.net/webbook/test.php

Comment: Please, review the first part of my answer. I shown you why you don't get an array and why it is always brings you only the last category name. Sorry if I wrote it unclear in some way. If you'll explain me what exactly the format of the array you want to see, I'll update the code accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain my problem the greatest. Right now I'm able to array out all of the categories correctly, but when it comes to events it's going to the latest id. This is a problem with the calendar.php I think. I will update my links to show the correct codes. My site has a live view of what it's doing too. Thank you for your help

Comment: OK, now I think I got it... Please, note what the event output is outside of the loop. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think you're answers are corresponding to my problems. You're giving me array help for viewwevent.php, but I'm passing a variable to that page so that won't matter (I don't think) I think this is more of a jquery problem.

Comment: I understand arrays, this problem is passing an array to a jquery plugin, I think.